# How to send WMS feature request

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am using [react-native-mapbox-gl](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl) in my react-native app. I want to send a feature request to WMS server. In openlayer I found a solution

```
        MyLayer.getSource()
        .getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate,
            map.getView().getResolution(),
            map.getView().getProjection(),  
            {
                'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json',
                'propertyName': 'OBJECTID,HOUSE_NUM'
            }
        );
```

This creates an URL of feature request. Is there any alternative method for "getGetFeatureInfoUrl" in mapbox-gl. Example will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct support for constructing a `GetFeatureInfo` request in Mapbox-GL-JS. You will need to construct it yourself, and make your own HTTP request.